# Read a website stream continuously

Tags: java, html, url, web, twitch

i wonder if there's a way to continuously read an InputStream of a website (URL) in Java?

I know how to get the pure html code of an URL, but thats not doing the job in this case:

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://www.twitch.tv/USERNAME").openStream();
```

Basically, what I want, is to get the chat of a Twitch channel. The problem is, when I use the code I showed in the example, it wont load new comments coming in.

Does anybody know a solution to this?

Comment: I think your only option is to frequently poll the Twitch site.  Maybe Twitch offers an API for this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out for APIs: http://dev.twitch.tv/

If it really doesn't work, you may consider to use a thread to constantly obtain the URL using a while loop.

Simple answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've sent them a request. What would be the alternate solution?

Comment: In case they didn't reply you...hum...I found this on github, wonder if it requires any authorization, hopefully not :) https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API